# Apigee as Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, apigee

I am trying to validate a JWT token from springboot generated by one of my custom apigee proxy. Wondering whether I can use spring security and use Apigee as authorization server to validate JWT?

Here  is my web security configuration

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
}
```

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri={apigee_endpoint}
```

Log says

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.wrapException(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:58) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.decode(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:49) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "{issuer_url}"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:166) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:93) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
```

Comment: I tried this, but got stuck with the issuer-uri.
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=

Not sure what would be the apigee issuer uri pattern. It keeps throwing error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of <uri>

Comment: Apparently the value of `{apigee_endpoint}` is `{issuer_url}`, but it must be a valid URI.

Comment: Thats right. Any guidance how would that value be for apigee edge?

Comment: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/jwt-policies-overview

Comment: The `issuer-uri` configures a standard discovery mechanism that the authorization server needs to implement. Typically, a well-known endpoint such as `https://apigee-host.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` must exist, and the issuer-uri property would be `https://apigee-host.com`. I'm not familiar with Apigee but it appears they do have features that ought to make this possible, however I can't find the docs that discuss it explicitly.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the input. I created a well known endpoint and instead issuer uri I supplied the jwk-set-uri which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when we used two different versions of keycloak. The path for one was

```
${security-provider-host-port}/auth/realms/${security-provider-realm}
```

for another

```
${security-provider-host-port}/realms/${security-provider-realm}
```

So, check your `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` path.